# Cannot use 'tail -f" despite has enough memory

Tags: linux, memory, ubuntu, tail

I got a problem with "tail -f", I cannot start it on my ubuntu machine. The message is "no memory left" (tail: kann *** nicht beobachten: Auf dem Gerät ist kein Speicherplatz mehr verfügbar).

No device has more than 4% usage and I also tried delete the logfile and start a new one. Any ideas what may cause the problem?

Comment: Is that an instanteneous response, or is it trying to read a lot of stuff from the hard drive first? (just trying to figure out if * is something massive). Also, have you tried reinstalling coreutils, the package that gives you tail?

Comment: Maybe your terminal window is scrolling too much (and eating memory)? Try in a new terminal emulator. Use `top` or `htop` or `ps auxw` to figure out which process is eating memory.

Comment: Please supply the _exact_ command you write and what kind of file you're trying to `tail`.

Comment: It is a textfile and the command I use is "tail -f app/logs/dev.log"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that works on my machine. It just needed a little "sudo" to run that command. The logfile belongs to my linuxuser and I got all permittions, but obviously thats not enough...

Answer (score 0):

The no more memory left problem is not due to a filesystem occupation.

You could launch `free` to verify the amount of free memory you have, and launch `top` to see who is eating all your memory.

Comment: There is enough memory free, also on harddisc.

total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3942952    2550492    1392460          0     221532    1003996
-/+ buffers/cache:    1324964    2617988
Swap:      4013052          0    4013052

Comment: @Daniel : OK, how are you launching the `tail -f` command, what is the size of the file, did you try a `less your_log_file` ?

Comment: @Daniel : as suggested by Miquel try to reinstall the `coreutils` package : `apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled the coreutils and started a new terminal window, but nothing changed.